# Backbone.js: view states and routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, url-routing

I'm thinking about the optimal way to structure my Backbone application. The problem is that I have various complex states, each made by some views showing while all the others are hidden.

What is the canonical way to handle this in Backbone? Two things that I've thought are either controlling the state by the router (calling views hide / show methods) or making the views listen for route event.

The problem with the first method is that the router must be aware of all the views existing in the application.

The problem with this second solution is that I have to make *all* the views listen to *all* the events and hide for any of them but a couple that make them show.

Thanks for pointing me to a lean solution.

Comment: an error model, status view subscribes to. Invoke error events through that model ( this way all the components are aware of a common bus model )

Answer (score 2):

I use a FSM machine to change the state of the application. Each states shows and hides the appropriate view.  My views use transition to animate in and out, so changing the state is more complex, then simple show/hide - it animates in and out from one state into another. I have forked https://github.com/fschaefer/Stately.js to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I can share my personal experience with such a problem. I don't know if it's the best solution, but it worked for me.

My problem was even worse because I had several routers and each of them should hide/show views that belong to it. The solution I chose was similar to the first option you consider.

In my router there is an array which holds all existing views. When the state changes and route callback executes all other views are hidden with this simple code `view[i].hide()` and the proper one is shown. You can make View model and Views collection if you would like to have more control.

I think it's a better solution, because when you add a new route, you don't have to add route events to all views. Moreover, your views stay decoupled from the router, they may even don't know it exists.